# System.Web.UI.ScriptManager' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. But it is in the assembly?

Tags: asp.net, .net, exception, web-config, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I just added Ajax to my website and i'm using toolkitscript manager, when i go to build it it produces the error.

> The type 'System.Web.UI.ScriptManager' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35

here is my entire web.config, I already see System>web>extensions referenced, what else could be the issue?

```
<system.web>
    <pages>
        <controls>
            <add tagPrefix="cc1" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit"/>
        </controls>
    </pages>
    <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.UI, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add assembly="System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
        <add assembly="System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
        <add assembly="System.ServiceModel.Activation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add assembly="System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.ApplicationServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add assembly="System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
        <add assembly="System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.ServiceModel.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Services.Client, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Services.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/></assemblies></compilation>
</system.web>
```

This is how it is in my aspx.

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>

<cc1:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
</cc1:ToolkitScriptManager>`
```

**EDIT**

Here is the solution:

`<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">`

It was missing targetFramework = "4.0"

Comment: i did add a reference and it still tells me i must add a reference

Comment: What is the type of your project? Web site or web app?

Comment: website all i wanted to do is add the script manager for ajax

Comment: Anyway, without any strong reasons to keep web project, I recommend you to convert it into web app.

Comment: how would that solve this issue?

Comment: Web app is actually a dll with regular references, as opposed to web site with it's virtual references in web.config, and all other crappy stuff.

Comment: converted, stil lwith same error

Comment: clean your web.config. also try with empty project

Comment: why would i do either?  I clean the web.config i just have to put everything back in it, and an empty project would exclude the aspx from my current project

Comment: Could there be a conflict with version numbers? For example does your project file refer to .NET Framework 3.5 and you've added a reference to 4.0 or vice versa?

Comment: found the answer ugh this was just dumb, judst freaking dumb 8 hours on that

Comment: @Mike: Please post as an answer, and then accept it.

Answer (score 11):

For all those who, like me, still have this problem after reading the solution, I can well highlight that it is essential to add the reference **System.Web.Extensions** (As mentioned in the question ).

```
<add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
```

Answer (score 10):

Add: targetFramework="4.0" to the compilation tag.

```
<compilation debug="true" **targetFramework="4.0"**>
```

Answer (score 0):

We just deleted the files with the warnings/errors and were planning on loading them back in but when deleted we republished with no errors and no issues so we never put them back in.  Just a suggestion but try it.