# Type System.Web.UI.UpdatePanel not defined

Tags: asp.net

The aspx page was working fine and after I added a asp:UpdatePanel, I started getting this message. I have added the required ajax register tags. Any pointers regarding the error would be helpful.

Comment: By `added the required ajax register tags` you mean you added ScriptManager?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter yes. added scriptmanager

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8105648/system-web-ui-scriptmanager-is-defined-in-an-assembly-that-is-not-referenced-b please refer this link